Is a direct summand of a dualisable object itself dualisable?
If an object $X$ in an abelian monoidal category is the direct summand of a dualisable object, is $X$ itself dualisable? This is true in the category of modules over a commutative ring, since then a module is dualisable if and only if it is finitely generated projective. What about more general monoidal categories?

This is now answered at the mathoverflow copy of the same question. Instead of abelian we just need idempotent-complete.
